# How to perform a query on a list of a custom type using map and set?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out how one would be able to use map and set to generate a list based on a custom type.

For example 'type Review' which consists of: type nameOfReviewer = String, type nameOfTool = String, type numberOfStars = Int.

How would I get a list of the names of the people that have left a review so that it fits that definition.

I have tried using Set.union but haven't had any luck.

```
module Reviews where

import Data.Set (Set)
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
type nameOfReviewer = String
type nameOfTool = String
type numberOfStars = Int

type Review = (nameOfReviewer, nameOfTool, numberOfStars)

-- list of people that have left a review.
reviewers :: [Review] -> [nameOfReviewer]
reviewers rl = ???
```

Comment: You can't start working on `reviewers` until you get the type definitions before it to start compiling.

Comment: You haven't actually written any custom types. You've just written *type synonyms*. The names of type synonyms, as well as those of datatypes and newtypes, must start with capital letters.

Comment: voting to close. needs details or clarity

Answer (score 0):

To write a custom type, you need to use the `data` or `newtype` keyword. `newtype` is only for types with a single constructor and a single field, so we'll use `data`.

```
data Review = Review
  { nameOfReviewer :: String
  , nameOfTool :: String
  , numberOfStars :: Int
  }
```

Should the number of stars really be any `Int`? Well, probably not, because it likely has to be between 1 and 5, or 0 and 10, or something. So that one deserves its own type.

```
newtype Stars = Stars Int

mkStars :: Int -> Maybe Stars
mkStars n
  | 1 <= n && n <= 5
  = Just (Stars n)
  | otherwise
  = Nothing

getStars :: Stars -> Int
getStars (Stars stars) = stars

data Review = Review
  { nameOfReviewer :: String
  , nameOfTool :: String
  , numberOfStars :: Stars
  }
```

Since `Stars` is a full-fledged type, you can export it abstractly, forcing users to use `mkStars` and `getStars` to interact with it, thereby maintaining the star number rules.